# Kendo ComboBox Change event Value method is not supported

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have a Kendo ComboBox in an EditorTemplate:  it looks like this:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
   .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:10px; background-color: #f4f4f4;" })
   .Name("myBox" )
   .Placeholder("Choose a value...")
   .DataTextField("Name")
   .DataValueField("Value")
   .DataSource( source => 
   {
       source.Read( read => read.Action( "GetItems", "MyBoxController" ) )
           .Events( e => e.Change( "ComboBoxChanged" ) );
   } )
)
```

The ComboBoxChanged function couldn't be simpler:

```
function ComboBoxChanged(e) {
    var value = this.value();
}
```

but, as the template comes up, it throws an error, "Object doesn't support property or method 'value'".  [This indicates to me that, at least the data-binding is working, causing some item in the ComboBox to be selected.]  What am I missing?  This looks just like all the examples to me, except, as I said, I'm in an EditorTemplate, rather than a main View.

Answer (score 2):

The ComboBoxChanged should be wired to the ComboBox Events, not the ComboBox DataSource Events.